# InstallShield - Set Directory Permissions To ALL Users

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, windows-installer, installshield

I'm using Install Shield 2015 Limited Edition in Visual Studio 2015.

I'm trying to set the permissions of the directory my application installs to, to allow all users: read & execute, list folder contents, read, write access.

I can't find where to do this using the Project Assistant.

I've looked into the .ISL and I can see

```
<col key="yes" def="s72">Directory</col>
<col def="S72">Directory_Parent</col>
<col def="l255">DefaultDir</col>
<col def="S255">ISDescription</col>
<col def="I4">ISAttributes</col>
<col def="S255">ISFolderName</col>
```

I'm assuming it's the `I4` attribute, but not sure what value to set for it.

Maybe I'm looking too much into this and there is a simpler way.

Thanks!

Comment: Assuming your application installs under the Program Files folder, you should not add write access to it. This is a big security no-no. Instead fix the application to write to some other directory.

Comment: @MichaelUrman why is this a bad idea? can you explain or provide a link that explains? thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Attributes refers to the standard file system attributes (read-only, hidden, etc.) What you're looking for is the *Permissions* settings.

I'm not familiar with the LE edition so I don't know if it can be done using the graphical interface (in InstallShield full edition it can be done [like this](http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield22helplib/helplibrary/ConfiguringPrmssnsFile.htm))

But you can always do the following: 
locate the ISLockPermissions table in your project file and add a row for your folder like this (YOURFOLDER refers to the folder entry in the 'Directory' table):

```
    <table name="ISLockPermissions">
    <col key="yes" def="s72">LockObject</col>
    <col key="yes" def="s32">Table</col>
    <col key="yes" def="S255">Domain</col>
    <col key="yes" def="s255">User</col>
    <col def="I4">Permission</col>
    <col def="I4">Attributes</col>
    <row><td>YOURFOLDER</td><td>CreateFolder</td><td>[%USERDOMAIN]</td><td>Users</td><td>131519</td><td>0</td></row>
</table>
```

131519 is the combined permission you asked for.

Edit: If it doesn't work with LE, another approach can be adding a custom action that sets the permission using the icacls command.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!